# QDockwidget closeEvent Pyqt4

Tags: pyqt4, qdockwidget

I am trying to catch the closeEvent of a QDockWidget in my GUI. But destroyed() doesn't work and I have tried everything else I can't seem to get it to work.

What would be the simplest solution for this. Maybe a two liner. Just to catch the Qdockwidget exit event and then print something for instance.
I have used Qt designer to create that widget.

cheers
Anns

Comment: `def fn(): print('something'); dock.closeEvent = fn`.

Comment: thank you so much for this. The only problem it is also triggered when the dockwidget is undocked or so. So it is a bit painful but thank you!

Comment: There may be a better solution - but it depends on specifiying exactly what you want to achieve. What do you mean by "exit event"? Some possibilities are: (1) application exit, (2) dock deleted, (3) dock closed (hidden), (4) dock undocked.